# How do you eliminate the gap between castle doors?

Tags: building

I'm building a MOC castle and want to use a pair of 1x5x7 and 1/2 stockade doors.  My problem: I can't get the doors to fit flush.  Either there's a 1/8 to 1/4 inch gap between them, or they overlap.  Are there published instructions from a castle Set which show how to set them flush?  Or, can someone please explain how to solve my problem?  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 9):

I'm assuming that you are referring to [this door](http://brickset.com/parts?query=30223):

[image: 30223]

These doors are designed for the hinge to attach from the back of the door and not the side, which might be what is tripping you up. There are ways to get these to line up with the hinge on the side, but the easiest fix is to just have them hinge from the back.

This part is used in many sets including [7036-1 Dwarves' Mine](http://brickset.com/sets/7036-1/Dwarves-Mine). Here's an example of this part in use from the instructions for that set:

[image: instruction page 13]